# Conditionally update parts of PUT request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to make a PUT request to my API every time a user clicks on a button.  However, it it should either:

1. update both `showAward` bool and points
2. OR just update the `showAward` bool

How do I do so without making the code bulky?

```
function Block() {
  async function handleDismissButton() {
   if (conditionMet) {
try {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/user/${userId}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: {
          showAward: true,
          points: points += 1
        }
      });
      const users = await response.json();
      return users;
    } catch (err) {
      return null;
    }
   } else {
try {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/user/${userId}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: {
          showAward: true
        }
      });
      const users = await response.json();
      return users;
    } catch (err) {
      return null;
    }
   }
  }


  return (
            <button
              role="button"
              onClick={() => handleDismissButton()}
            >
              Click here
            </button>
          
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the `points` key if the condition is met:

```js
function Block() {
    async function handleDismissButton() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`/api/user/${userId}`, {
                method: "PUT",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: {
                    showAward: true,
                    ...(conditionMet && { points: points + 1 })
                },
            });
            const users = await response.json();
            return users;
        } catch (err) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    return (
        <button role="button" onClick={handleDismissButton}>
            Click here
        </button>
    );
}
```